# Cannot access /var/www from Live Session

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

For some reason Ubuntu won't boot.
I want to recover my files from `/var/www/`.

When I boot into live session, and go to `/var`, the `/www` folder isn't there anymore.

I try using `blkid`, and the HDD is listed as /dev/sdb1, however when I mount that using `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`, I just get the same as navigating there from Nautilus.

How can I access the files there?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that:

1. You want to retrieve `/var/www` files from a Computer which doesn't boot.
2. You plugged into that computer a live-boot CD/USB and managed to boot the computer
3. You have no access to the original `/var/www` folder
4. You tried mounting `/dev/sdb1` and you got the same folder structure has you see using `Nautilus`

It seems like you mounted the live-boot CD/USB into `/mnt` and hence you didn't manage to access the original `/var/www` folder.

**Suggested Solution:**

I'd suggest trying `/dev/sda1` which might be the name of the original hard-disk of your computer (which doesn't boot), and look there for the `/var/www` folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Note: The following command will list all devices on your computer:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If `/dev/sda1` doesn't exists / doesn't contain the folder you are looking for, you can try other devices which will be listed by the above command

Note also: `man blkid` suggest to use `lsblk --fs` instead of `blkid`.

Answer (score 1):

Because a Live CD/USB is not your Ubuntu installation, so the path of `/var/www` is a path of the Live session.

To reach your SSD/HDD files of your Ubuntu installation graphically, once inside the desktop environment with the "Try Ubuntu" option of Live CD/USB, open a file manager window and click on the hard drive name. Once within the hard drive, navigate to where your files are located, in your case, `/var/www`.

Or just do the `sudo mount /dev/sdxX /mnt/hdd` command and go to `/mnt/hdd/var/www`.